# PHP MySQL Dialogflow

Tags: php, mysql, dialogflow-es

I'm setting up a chatbot (dialogflow) with a PHP webhook 
What I want to do is to take the user input to query a MySQL table and pass the result back to the dialogflow API
So far I succeeded with passing a text string back to the API, but I don't understand how to query the database and pass the result back to the dialogflow API
I'll appreciate your help with this 
I've used the API format from the dialogflow docs [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment)
This is what I have

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == 'POST') {
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$json = json_decode($requestBody); 
$text = $json->result->parameters->cities;
$conn = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM exampletable LIKE '%".$_POST["cities"]."%'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
$speech = $emparray;
    $response->speech = $speech;
    $response->displayText = $speech;
    $response->source = "webhook";
    echo json_encode(array($response,$emparray));
else
{
    echo "Method not allowed";
}
 ?>
```

Thankyou

Comment: You have SQL injection in your code.. must read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever the webhook gets triggered you need to listen to `actions` from JSON responses, 
from the `action` made the switch case of `actions`

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'get_enews.php';

function processMessage($input) {
    $action = $input["result"]["action"];
    switch($action){

        case 'getNews':
            $param = $input["result"]["parameters"]["number"];
            getNews($param);
            break;

        default :
            sendMessage(array(
                "source" => "RMC",
                "speech" => "I am not able to understand. what do you want ?",
                "displayText" => "I am not able to understand. what do you want ?",
                "contextOut" => array()
            ));
    }
}
function sendMessage($parameters) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $data = str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($parameters));
    echo $data;
}
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (isset($input["result"]["action"])) {
    processMessage($input);
}
?>
```

**get_enews.php**

```
<?php
function getNews($param){
    require 'config.php';
    $getNews="";
    $Query="SELECT link FROM public.news WHERE year='$param'";
    $Result=pg_query($con,$Query);
    if(isset($Result) && !empty($Result) && pg_num_rows($Result) > 0){
    $row=pg_fetch_assoc($Result);
    $getNews= "Here is details that you require - Link: " . $row["link"];
        $arr=array(
            "source" => "RMC",
            "speech" => $getNews,
            "displayText" => $getNews,
        );
        sendMessage($arr);
    }else{
        $arr=array(
            "source" => "RMC",
            "speech" => "No year matched in database.",
            "displayText" => "No year matched in database.",
        );
        sendMessage($arr);
    }
}
?>
```

So when the action gets caught it will get executed and goes in the `getNews($param);` function here I am getting `year` as a response from the user in my case and I am executing the query in the database and giving back a response from the database.

Comment: dude you are awesome it worked! If you could point me to documentation where I can learn how to figure this out myself I'll appreciate it

Comment: i don't have documentation, you can ask questions

Comment: Hello, i am also trying to connect dialogflow with mysql, can you please point me to some tutorial which uses php