# Webhook does not work to connect Dialogflow with PHP script

Tags: php, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I am using DIalogflow (api.ai) to create chat interfaces. For now, I only have a simple intent called 'Name'regarding the question 'Who is *name*?' which responds '*name* is a great person'. The json output regarding this question from Dialoglow is the following:

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "timestamp": "2018-03-20T12:38:27.972Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Who is John",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "given-name": "John"
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "...",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 242,
      "intentName": "Name"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "John is a",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "John is a"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $.",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "491d57cb-0af2-45ac-a658-9e47ec6658ce",
  "alternativeResultsFromKnowledgeService": {}
```

Notice that the json output states an error regarding the webhook: `"Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $."`

I want to create a webhook to (a simple app containing) a php script deployed on Heroku to give another answer. An example of this php script would be:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == 'GET'){
    $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($requestBody);

    $text = $json->metadata->intentName->text;

    switch ($text) {
        case 'Name':
            $speech = "This question is too personal";
            break;

        default:
            $speech = "Sorry, I didnt get that.";
            break;
    }

    $response = new \stdClass();
    $response->speech = $speech;
    $response->displayText = $speech;
    $response->source = "webhook";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    echo "Method not allowed";
}
```

Also notice that `$method` is `GET` for some reason instead of `POST` as it is supposed to be from Dialogflow.

Keep also in mind that if you try to `echo` any of the variables `$requestBody`, `$json` or `$text` then nothing is printed.

This is printed to the webpage where the app is deployed by Heroku:

```
{"speech":"Sorry, I didnt get that. Please ask me something else.","displayText":"Sorry, I didnt get that. Please ask me something else.","source":"webhook"}
```

How can I fix these errors and connect dialogflow with my php script on Heroku?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363518/php-mysql-dialogflow

Comment: Thanks but to refer to what? I simply use the value of the `intentName` instead of the value of `action` to determine my response. There is not any significant difference by doing either of these.

Comment: Try debuging with `ngrok` so you can find error localy and then deploy it to heroku