# Webhooks for slot filling

Tags: python, node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am having trouble with slot/parameter filling in dialogflow. I am not able to search any good documentation for how to use webhooks/backend-code for parameter filling.

My use case is, I want to extract `date` but if the user is not providing YEAR then it should ask the user "which year?". And then fill it back in `date`.

I am using `$date.partial` as `value` so it is giving `UUUU` for the year part, but how can I prompt the user to give the year so that I can fill it in the parameter to get complete date.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put the link of the screenshot how you are asking a date to a user ?

Comment: simply by making an entity on dialogflow console and checking it as `required` @NikhilSavaliya

Comment: then add the question in as parameter in dialogFLow

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya oh yes, i mostly work with Amazon Lex hence the mistake. corrected and added screenshot for better understanding. thanks.

Comment: set date as required and in prompt ask for a year if a year is not entered.

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya if the user is not entering the year then it will consider year as `UUUU`, so the value of date will be something like `UUUU-03-01`. so the prompt will not work. however if i can handle it programatically (using webhooks for slot filling) then it can be solved. i have mentioned in the question details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363518/php-mysql-dialogflow/49364638#49364638 refer this for code and in dialogFlow as choose options for slot filling and it will work.

Comment: Are you still trying to do this? I don't know python but can give you a nodejs example, and the Dialogflow console configuration to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i have found a way to do that and will be adding the answer soon, still you can add the answer so that it would help many others like me. thanks! and language is not a constraint. :)

Comment: @sid8491 Done!, It's a little long, but it does work! I use it in my multiple agents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes setting a param as `required` is not enough, because you don't only need that param to be present, but you need it in a specific format, there's an alternative using `events`.

There are multiple steps, but once you're familiar with it, you'll do it very fast.

**1)** Create 2 new intents: `Year - Confirmation` & `Year - Confirmed`

**2)** Add an event in the first intent: Intent > Events > `ask-year` (or whatever name you like)

**3)** Add an **output context**: `year-confirmation`

**4)** Set a response asking the user to enter the year: `Please provide the year...`

**5)** Set parameter:

- **Name**: date
- **Entity:** -
- **Value:** `#ask-year.date`  (This will come from event data, you will send it from your backend)

[image]

**6)** On your second intent `Year - Confirmed`, add as **input context**: `year-confirmation` (the output from the previous intent)

**7)** Set the same action as your main intent: `insurance`

**8)** Add some training phrases where you can match the year:

- 2017 (@sys.number:year)
- The year is @sys.number:year (Use template mode for this one)

[image]

Now you will have `$year` as params.

**9)** Add one extra parameter:

- **Name**: date
- **Entity:** -
- **Value:** `#year-confirmation.date`  (This will come from year-confirmation context)

[image]

**10)** On your backend, when you receive the incompleted date you should send `ask-year` event.

**Node.js example, I don't know python**

```js
const apiai = require('apiai');
const client = apiai('my-dev-token');

function sendEvent(data) {

    const request = client.eventRequest(data, {
        sessionId: 'current-session'
    });

    request.on('response', response => {
        // Push message to your UI
        console.log(response.result.fulfillment.speech); // Please provide the year...
    });

    request.on('error', error => {
        console.error('Event error: ', error);
    });

    request.end();

}

/* ... */

// Your insurance action handler
function insuranceHandler(result) {

    const { parameters } = result;

    if(parameters.date || parameters.date.includes('UUUU')) { // Or whatever check for invalid year

        // Send previous date as data, so you will have it in the event response
        return sendEvent({
            name: 'ask-year',
            data: {
                date: parameters.date
            }
        });

    }

    // Year comes from `ask-year` intent
    if(parameters.year)
        parameters.date = parameters.date.replace('UUUU', parameters.year);

    // Do whatever you need
}
```

Now when the date is incomplete, the event will be triggered, executing `Year - Confirmation` and you will be asked to provide the year. After you provide one, `Year - Confirmed` intent will be executed by your response. Now your backend will receive the `insurance` action with an additional parameter, `year`

Comment: Glad to help! Let's hope they provide a parameter validation option to avoid this work around :)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande hey i have a question, what if there are similar multiple parameters and we want to handle it using intents instead of slots, then how would we track the values of these parameters until we reach the final intent?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Your solution seems like you are triggering a new intent to capture the year.  What if I alrady have the year and want to set it properly in the context of the initial intent?  Is it possible to do it programmatically with fulfillment?

Comment: @agwntr you can send the year directly either as an event or using `detectIntent` and sending a context with the parameters. If I'm not mistaken fulfillment works only as webhook, I will need to know your exact case in order to help you.

Answer (score -3):

Check the box next to the parameter labeled `Required` and click `Add prompt` on the right of the parameter and add the prompt `Which year?`

Comment: that's not gonna help since the user will be entering a date, without the year, so the parameter value will be filled.